# Android Location Service Launch Issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-location, location-services

What it's suppose to do is turn on location when needed and turn off location when not needed. I am having trouble with my Location Service when I tap to turn on location service it says, "app has stopped" please find my logcat below. any help is truely appreciated. Thank You

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.kenpar.dmsassign2, PID: 21749
              java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE from pid=21749, uid=10184
                  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1472)
                  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1426)
                  at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerNative.java:2640)
                  at android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast(ContextImpl.java:1499)
                  at android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast(ContextWrapper.java:377)
                  at com.kenpar.dmsassign2.LocationActivity$1.onClick(LocationActivity.java:30)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19274)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                  Application terminated.
```

Location java code:

```
public class LocationActivity extends Activity {
Button onLoc;
Button offLoc;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_location);

    onLoc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.onLoc);
    offLoc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.offLoc);

    onLoc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick (View view){
            Intent intent = new Intent ("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
            intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    });

    offLoc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick (View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
        intent.putExtra("enabled", false);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.location, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see what error you get, can you supply the entire exception from the logcat. And where exactly is line 30 in the LocationActivity?

Comment: @FredrikMetcalf Please see edit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On android version 4.4 and above you cannot manually turn location services on and off. It will throw a `securityException` and can only be done manually. What you can do, you can move the user to the location services settings screen when location services are required by firing this intent:

```
startActivity(context, new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
```

Comment: I never knew. thanks for the advice. @Talha Mir how exactly would i incorporate that line of code?

Comment: Where ever you need to switch on Location services. You can show a dialog to the user indicating that a certain action requires him to switch on location service. If he taps 'Yes' , fire the above intent. That will be a good User Experience.

Comment: @kokonut43 Glad it helped. Accept the answer if it worked.